# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION with Problematic frame: #j

Tags: java, crash, crash-dumps, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

We have been getting the following hot spot error very frequently in recent past.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000020dcfe8, pid=5104, tid=5724
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  com.company.common.Stack.getSomething(Ljava/util/ArrayList;Z)[Lcom/company/common/key/SomeKey;+61
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

we have not changed any part of the code in the recent past except for following changes

1. Windows upgraded from 32-bit to 64-bit
2. Java runtime upgraded from 32-bit to 64-bit
3. SQL server upgraded for 2005 to 2014.

Have no idea what is cause the issue. Can someone please help me. I can provide the full error dump if needed.

Have already searched the web but did not find much of information for

```
# Problematic frame:
# j
```

Comment: Report this at http://bugreport.java.com/

Answer (score 0):

Couple be a possible JVM bug. Since you said you have been getting this exception frequently, try running for a while with the latest 1.6 patch (which you have to get through the archives) or try running on 1.7.

Comment: This doesn't look like a JVM issue as the problematic frame is com.company.common.Stack.getSomething(Ljava/util/ArrayList;Z)[Lcom/company/common/key/SomeKey;+61

May be you need to check the logic issue in your program.